How to set COM port to half duplex mode using C++ on Windows
I need to be able to configure a Windows COM port to half duplex operation, using C++.
The background to this is that we have some legacy hardware that only operates in half duplex mode and we need to replicate an existing connection to a Windows PC within a new C++ application. We don't have access to original Windows side software so can't see how it was previously done.
Is the Flow Control setting what I'm needing?
I've looked at Software Flow Control but that appears as though it won't be suitable because we can't have the XON/XOFF bits appearing in the data stream.
Hardware Flow Control looks like it may be what I'm after but I'm suspecting I will then need to toggle the RTS and CTS lines within the software?
Or I'm missing?
Apologies if this is a seemingly dumb question I've only ever used the COM ports in full duplex mode.

You need to be more specific... What kind of "COM port"? Is it an RS-232 port? RS-485? Something else? And flow control for e.g. RS-232 isn't really about "duplex". RS-232 is inherently "full duplex" per its specification. What is the actual and underlying problem you need to solve? What is your task or assignment? Why do you need to set the COM-port itself to "half duplex" instead of putting it into the protocol used for the communication?

Deleted my previous comment as it was wrong.... It's RS-232 but definitely operating in half duplex mode. We have an existing system which we need to replicate. A   Windows PC will have a USB to RS232 adapter to communicate with some legacy hardware. We need to configure the PC's port for half duplex because that's what the UART on the hardware expects (and we can't change that). The comms protocol is GI74 (which was a standard defined in the 1970's so it's not possible to modify the protocol).
